# Remove a portion of the displayed url without changing $_GET using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, get

Currently my .htaccess code sends the `{REQUEST_URI}` as a `$_GET` array to `load.php` where that page calls up the controllers for the request. For SEO purposes, I would like to remove a portion of the URL without changing the `$_GET` array that is sent to `load.php`.

For example if I have:

```
domain.com/products/product-name
```

I would like the URL to display:

```
domain.com/product-name
```

without changing the `$_GET` variable that is sent to `load.php`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've included my current code.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**CLARIFICATION:**

`$_GET[0]` serves as a 'controller' variable which directs the application to open up the appropriate file. Therefore, I can't hardcode 'products' into `$_GET[0]` because that would constantly open up `controllers/products.php` instead of the appropriate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the URL to display:
>
> domain.com/product-name
>
> **without changing the $_GET** variable that is
>   sent to load.php.

The only way to do what you're asking is to hardcode part of the URL in the substitution string of the rewriterule with `products`. See below. Then URL load.php will always receive `products/somefile`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=products/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Update: This solution will work if you have one path/controller you want to substitute.

You have to reference the controller some how. So if you don't have the controller in the request there is nothing to forward to the $_GET variable. PHP will not know where the request is supposed to go. There is nothing wrong with having that in the path and it should not affect your SEO.

Comment: Ok. So I've tried that, but I don't want products on every $_GET variable. Is there an if statement I can use? I tried looking for one but couldn't figure it out...

Comment: You said without changing the $_GET variable. What exactly is it that you want to do? Please update your question.

Comment: Done. Basically $_GET[0] servers as a controller variable and directs the program to open up the correct file. Therefore, I can't stick a constant variable in $_GET[0]

Comment: Ok then that's not possible. You have to reference the controller some how. How else do you think it will know which one to use? I thought you only have one path/controller. SEO is not about making the URL the shortest possible URL. Having the controller in the URL is not a problem. You are already rewriting it the URL.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. If you put it as the an answer, I'll mark it. Thanks for all your help and for hanging in there until there was a solution. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Blaisen I've updated to answer to provide more info similar to our comments.